# Increment the Mongoose query limit by button click/scroll in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to increment the data via Button click or scroll.

I have a function which loads the data after button click `loadDataQueryDB(param, param, param)`. With that, I am passing data to `MongoDB` query.

Well how can I increment my `var limit =  50;` + 5; after each button click?

**Node.js**

```
router.get('/load', function(req, res) {
    var skip =  0;
    var limit =  50;
    var place_val = req.query.place;
    var category_val = req.query.category;
    var specCategory_val = req.query.specCategory;
    if(category_val, specCategory_val, place_val){    
        Experiences
            .find({category : category_val, city:place_val})
            .lean()
            .skip(skip)
            .limit(limit)
            .exec(function(err, docs_accommo) {

                res.send(docs_accommo);
                console.log("First");


        });
    }
});
```

**Angular.js**

```
app.controller('loadData', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$upload', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $http, $window, $upload, $rootScope) {

  $scope.loadDataQueryDB = function(place_value, category_value, specCategory_value){
    console.log(place_value);
    console.log(category_value);
    console.log(specCategory_value);    

        $scope.datafront = [];
        var options = {
            place : place_value, 
            category: category_value,
            specCategory : specCategory_value
        };

            $http.get('/load',
                     {params: options})
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.datafront = data;
            }); 
    };

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-click="loadDataQueryDB(place, category, specCategory)">
    <div ng-repeat="x in datafront | limitTo:? track by x._id" ng-cloak>
        {{x}}
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default"  style="float:right; margin-bottom:20px;"/>
```

Comment: I think you have messed up with ternary operator while setting `limitTo` value

Comment: What about using a http promise and reaload only the ng-repeat object?, that will solve your problem.
See: http://augustolemble.com/post?id=56843e1c12ba70244b792e4f

Comment: @Augusto, it looks good, but how can I increment the appearing data? How would you write this code?

Comment: Added as an answer below, I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the code below, using services and http promises, the data returned form the server its on promise.data.

```
app.controller('loadData', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$upload', '$rootScope','dataService',
    function($scope, $http, $window, $upload, $rootScope, dataService) {

  $scope.loadDataQueryDB = function(place_value, category_value, specCategory_value){
    console.log(place_value);
    console.log(category_value);
    console.log(specCategory_value);    

        $scope.datafront = [];
        var params = {
            place : place_value, 
            category: category_value,
            specCategory : specCategory_value
            skip : $scope.skip,
            limit : $scope.limit
            }
        dataService.getData(params).then(function(promise){
            $scope.dataFront = promise.data;
            //Increment the limit by ten
            $scope.limit =+ 10;
        })

    };

});    
app.module('dataService').factory('dataService',['$http',function ($http) {

    var service = {};

    factory.getData= function (params) {
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/load',
            params: params
        });
        return promise;
    }

    return service;

}]);
```

You should have only the gets that return views on the router and the rest of the get and post calls on a service, at least I develop like that and its more confortable.

Comment: Ok and is there any way to load the next 5 documents?

Comment: To load controllers and sevrices separated in documents?

Comment: I mean for example on button click with ng-click="loadMore()". After I clicked on the button it should load the next data. If I load huge files even with promise it takes time. Therefore I will need to limit() and skip() the data as previous. However I will use promise as well.

Comment: Ho I miss that, weel you will need to have the function
`$scope.loadMore = function(){
dataService.getData(params).then(function(promise){
      $scope.dataFront = promise.data;
})}`
on your controller, and increment the limit variables everytime you use it.

Comment: I didn't understand. The question is how can I increment it limit()

Comment: You can define a $scope variable and increment it, for example if you  want to increment the limit by ten every time you click it will be like this:  ´$scope.limit = 10;  $scope.loadMore = function(){  
dataService.getData({skip : 0, limit : $scope.limit}).then( function(promise) {  
 $scope.dataFront = promise.data;  $scope.limit =+ 10;  })  }´

Comment: @TonyCenoti is teh answer ok? if so, can you mark it as ok?

Comment: obvously its not copy/paste man, you need to change some things to make it work on your code. Every time you change the angular vscope varibale where you have teh array it should update teh ng-repeat element, if not reload that element yourself using jquery or something like that.